# Possible to see what stored proc procedure was previously before I changed it?

Tags: sql-server-2017

I replaced a proc with an updated version from another db, however the proc had some new changes itself that I overwrote in the process.

Not a huge problem as it's a dev db and I can restore from a backup... except that I will have to go track down where the backup is and restore it and what a pain.

I don't suppose there is any helpful system table in SQL that might show me what the definition was before I changed it? Guessing not, but figured it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short the only way to answer is No.

Sql Server does not track changes to your procedures or other objects, it is not a version control system - unfortunately that's a separate process you (no doubt) have in place. Numerous solutions exist for this that integrate with various repositories such as SVN or Git, such as [Redgate Sql Source Control](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/)

A little known feature allows you to append a number after the name of a procedure to create your own versions; it's indicated as deprecated in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but still works in SQL 2019.

Comment: Nope, no source control for SQL sadly. Wouldn't be asking this question if we did! I actually have a great solution for that which I love and have recommended but "oh yeah, that's a good idea... it would be great to look into that when we have some time". Of course, there's never time, lol. On a bright side though, it turned out the only problem I had was that I thought I had a problem. I actually didn't mess anything up this time. :)